# Manual Animation doesn't work in Cocos2d-x

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x

I'm testing manual animation. However, the animation seems to have some issues, so it doesn't work.

These are the code. Can you take a look and let me where I'm wrong.

**HelloWorldScene.h**

```
#ifndef __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
#define __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__

#include "cocos2d.h" 
#include <string>
USING_NS_CC;

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor{
public:
// Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
virtual bool init();  

// there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();

// a selector callback
void menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender);

// implement the "static node()" method manually
CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);    

virtual void onEnter();

protected:
CCSprite*    m_grossini;

};
#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
```

**HelloWorldScene.cpp**

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h" 

USING_NS_CC;

CCScene* HelloWorld::scene()
{
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    HelloWorld *layer = HelloWorld::create();

    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}

bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !CCLayerColor::initWithColor( ccc4(255,255,255,255) ) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

    CCMenuItemImage *pCloseItem = CCMenuItemImage::create(
                                        "CloseNormal.png",
                                        "CloseSelected.png",
                                        this,
                                        menu_selector(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback));

    pCloseItem->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width - pCloseItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                                origin.y + pCloseItem->getContentSize().height/2));

    CCMenu* pMenu = CCMenu::create(pCloseItem, NULL);
    pMenu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
    this->addChild(pMenu, 1);

    CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();

    m_grossini = CCSprite::create("grossini.png");
    m_grossini->retain();
    this->addChild(m_grossini);
    m_grossini->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2));
    return true;
}

void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender)
{
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WINRT) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8)
    CCMessageBox("You pressed the close button. Windows Store Apps do not implement a close button.","Alert");
#else
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    exit(0);
#endif
#endif
}

void HelloWorld::onEnter(){
    CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::create();
    for( int i=1;i<15;i++)
    {
        char szName[100] = {0};
        sprintf(szName, "grossini_dance_%02d.png", i);
        animation->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(szName);
    }
    // should last 2.8 seconds. And there are 14 frames.
    animation->setDelayPerUnit(2.8f / 14.0f);
    animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true); 
    CCAnimate* action = CCAnimate::create(animation);
    m_grossini->runAction(CCSequence::create(action, action->reverse(), NULL));
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: "doesn't work" means what exactly?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: It doesn't animate although it seems to load images to create the animation

Comment: you need to give us some logcat error or tell us in which line your code is not working?

Comment: @SumitKandoi: it doesn't have error, the animation doesn't animate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following things:..

First of all remove this line `m_grossini->retain();` because addchild automatically increase its retain count.

Found the problem..

As you are overriding the `OnEnter` method you need to call it manually for the base class. In your case adding the line:-

```
    CCLayerColor::onEnter();
```

in the OnEnter method will do the work.

In future be careful while overriding base class methods.

Comment: I tried to remove m_grossini->retain(); and try your solution. However, the animation isn't affected. I meant it just appears the sprite which I added and no more. Besides, the onEnter is called :(

Comment: try using CCLayer instead of CCLayerColor . I don't understand why you are even using it.

Comment: I changed all but nothing is solved. I use CCLayerColor because I want to set the background is white as the example in the website

Comment: make sure it can find the files with the names you are entering.. (if files are not found you would see an error in the log "file fileName not found")    and lastly you could try putting it in the init method itself instead of OnEnter method

Comment: They all loaded because when I tried to change wrong name, it showed the warning load failed

Comment: check out the above answer again I'm sure this will resolve your issue.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::create();

for( int i=1;i<15;i++)

animation->addSpriteFrameWithFileName((CCString::createWithFormat("grossini_dance_%02d.png",i)->getCString()));
// should last 2.8 seconds. And there are 14 frames.
 animation->setDelayPerUnit(2.8f / 14.0f);
 animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true); 
 CCAnimate* action = CCAnimate::create(animation);
 m_grossini->runAction(action);  //Run once all frame(OR) 
 m_grossini->runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(action)); //Run RepeatForever
```